# Changing Background color of window on button click in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I developing qml project in that i want to add functionality of changing background color ..

for that i create one combo box with items {red,blue,white} and create one update button to update color  when user select  red item  and click on update background color change as red  so how can i do ??

```
Button {
            id: button1
            x: 284
            y: 95
            width: 114
            height: 34
            text: qsTr("Update")


            contentItem: Text {

                   font: control.font
                   opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
                   text: "Update"
                   //Font.pixelSize:15
                   horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                   verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                   elide: Text.ElideRight
               }
            background: Rectangle {
                       id: myRectId1
                       color: Colorchange.Rectange_Color
                       radius: 8
                   }
            onHoveredChanged: hovered ? myRectId1.opacity = 1 :
            myRectId1.opacity = .80;
            MouseArea {
                   id: mouseAreaScanbtn
                   anchors.fill: parent
                   hoverEnabled: true;
                   onEntered: { myRectId1.border.width = 2 }
                   onExited: { myRectId1.border.width = 1 }
                   onClicked: {
      //i want to add some code here to change background color
      // i tried 
            //window.color:combobox.currantindex()
}
               }
        }
```

Comment: The simplest way is to put `Rectangle` as a child of the main window with `anchor.fill: parent` attribute and so set its color as you need.

Comment: folibis Thank you for replay...my question is changing color dynamically  as per user Requirement...if user click on red color the background color set as red when click on update btn

Comment: That exactly I was talking about. You can change the color of the bg rectangle dynamically, from the ComboBox handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi just use ComboBox Qml type like this:

```
ComboBox {

        currentIndex: -1
        width: 200
        model: [ "white", "blue" , "red" ]
        onCurrentIndexChanged:{

             background.color=model[currentIndex]

        }


}
```

or if you want to update the background color after user click the button you should save the color that user selected in a property then use this in onClicked of your button:

```
Item {
    id:root 
    property  var SelectedColor
    ComboBox {

        currentIndex: -1
        width: 200
        model: [ "white", "blue" , "red" ]
        onCurrentIndexChanged:{

             SelectedColor=model[currentIndex]

        }



}
```

Comment: there is no need to duplicate color names, you can do `background.color=model[currentIndex]`. The idea of MVC is that view knows nothing about model.

Comment: thank you sir .....I have one more question ..i want to read color form color.ini file and set to background and also text,buttons  colors when onCurrentIndexChanged     color.ini file contents  2 sections [theme1].  backgroundcolor=red......textcolor=white....butoncolor=pink  . [theme2].....backgroundcolor=white......textcolor=blackj....butoncolor=pink ...